# Subvarieties of an abstract affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-varieties, ringed-spaces

I'm really confused on how to transfer constructions from "concrete" affine varieties (i.e. zeroes of polynomial equations in an affine space) and (abstract) affine varieties (i.e. ringed spaces isomorphic to a "concrete" affine variety). (I'm studying Algebraic Geometry from the [Gathmann's Notes](https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf))

For example it's clear to me that the subvarieties $Y$ of an affine variety $X$ should be the closed subsets (because for every isomorphism between $X$ and a concrete affine variety, closed subsets are always mapped exactly in the "concrete" subvarieties).

But it's not totally clear to me how to define the sheaf structure of $Y$, because I see two possibilities and I don't know why they are compatible:

- We fix an isomorphism $\mathbf{I}:X\to X'\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}$ and we define the structure sheaf of $Y$ as the pullback of the sheaf of regular functions of $\mathbf{I}(Y)$. Obviously this is just a definition up to isomorphism.
- We define the structure sheaf $\mathscr{O}_Y$ as:

$$\small{\mathscr{O}_Y(V):=\{\psi:V\to \mathbb{K}: \text{ for every } v\in V \text{ there is an open neighbourhood } U_v\subseteq X\text{ and a function } \varphi\in \mathscr{O}_X(U_v) \text{ such that } \psi|_{V\cap U_v}=\varphi|_{V\cap U_v} \}}$$

I don't see how this definitions can be compatible, since the first one is dependent on the choice of an isomorphism and the second doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the first option may appear as if it depends on the choices made, it actually does not. This is essentially the same process as upgrading from considering a manifold as some specified subset of $\Bbb R^n$ to consider a manifold as an abstract topological space.

Gathmann defines the structure sheaf on an affine variety $X\subset \Bbb A^n$ as follows: the sections over an open $U\subset X$ are functions $\varphi:U\to k$ such that for every $u\in U$ there are $f,g\in A(X)=k[t_1,\cdots,t_n]/I(X)$ with $g(u)\neq 0$ such that in an open neighborhood of $u$, we have $\varphi=\frac{f}{g}$. If $Y\subset X\subset \Bbb A^n$ is a closed subvariety, then we can use this definition to recover the second characterization: if $V\subset Y$ is an open subset  and $\psi:V\to k$ is a function such that there are $f,g\in A(Y)$ so that for every $v\in V$ we have that $\psi=\frac{f}{g}$ on an open neighborhood, then replacing $f$ and $g$ with lifts $\overline{f},\overline{g}\in A(X)$ under the surjective ring homomorphism $A(X)\to A(Y)$, then near $v$, the function $\psi$ is the restriction of $\frac{\overline{f}}{\overline{g}}$ which is a perfectly good function on an open neighborhood of $v\in X$.

Conversely, suppose we take the second definition. Then a function $\psi:V\to K$ is regular at $v\in V$ iff there is an open neighborhood $U_v\subset X$ and a $\varphi\in\mathcal{O}_X(U_v)$ such that $\psi$ is the restriction of $\varphi$ near this point. By the definition of the structure sheaf on $X$, we may write $\varphi=\frac{f}{g}$ on $U'\subset U$, a smaller open neighborhood of $v\in X$. Then, letting $\overline{f},\overline{g}\in A(X)$ be the images of $f,g\in A(X)$ under the map $A(X)\to A(Y)$, we have $\frac{\overline{f}}{\overline{g}}=\psi$ on $U'\cap Y$, an open neighborhood of $v\in V$. So if we take the second definition of the structure sheaf on a subvariety, we recover the first definition.

Comment: I don't quite get how to recover the first definition from the second one.

Comment: @Kandinskij I've added some material, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!